# Need to Add copied Text from the above line in a file to the following line where it has to be placed

Tags: unix

I need to copy text from the above line which matches "DIV(" and place the value in the line where subtotal is shown. The subtotal is not in the report. We need to add that also in the report along with values.

Please help me on this. How to  write a shell script or using awk or sed.

Report format:

```
03/27/2012 -   Emails Counts

Test1 DIV(12345)                  
Storenum    Add Change
----------- ---- ------
Store1      1      0                    
            ---- ------
            1      0
Test2 DIV(435335)                
Storenum    Store Name       Add Change 
----------- --------------- ---- ------
Store2        Test Store2     2      1
Store3        Test Store3     5      1
Store4        Test Store4     0      1
                            ---- ------
                              7      3
                            ---- ------                                    
Grand Total                  8       3
```

Tobeformated to

```
03/27/2012 -   Emails Counts

Test1 DIV(12345)                  
Storenum                    Add Change
-----------                 ---- ------
Store1                       1      0                    
                            ---- ------
Test1 DIV(12345) Subtotal    1      0
Test2 DIV(435335)                
Storenum    Store Name       Add Change 
----------- --------------- ---- ------
Store2        Test Store2     2      1
Store3        Test Store3     5      1
Store4        Test Store4     0      1
                            ---- ------
Test2 DIV(435335) Subtotal    7      3
                            ---- ------                                    
Grand Total                  8       3
```

Comment: What have you tried? You can hire someone to do it for you, but without any input on your part, nobody will help you with nonexistent problems.

Comment: If you're building that report from a database (I hope so), you'd do well to invest the time to learn how to write queries that produce the output you need. Coding something like this will be a maintenance nightmare! ;-)!!! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
next unless /DIV\(/;
print;
s/\s+$//;
$div  = $_." Subtotal";
$head = <>;
$_    = <>;
$pos  = index $_, " ---- ";
sub insbl { substr $_[0], $pos, 0, " "x(27-$pos); }
insbl $head; print $head;
insbl $_;    print;
do { insbl $_ = <>; print; } until /----/;
$_ = $div.<>;
substr $_, 27, $pos-27+length($div), "";
```